# .NET 5: Import was not found or had errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, grpc, .net-5

A simple scenario derived from the well-known introductory example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). In order to make the `HelloRequest` message reusable I extracted it in another file – **request.proto**. The file is in the same folder as the original **greet.proto** (see the picture at the end).

I need to make `HelloRequest` (in **request.proto**) known to the `Greeter` service (in **greet.proto**). All attempts to import it in greet.proto failed with the message

```
...
1>Protos/greet.proto(7,1): error : Import "request.proto" was not found or had errors.
...
```

Here are the greet.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcService1";

package greeter;

import "request.proto";
//import "Protos/request.proto";
//import "GrpcService1/Protos/request.proto";
// all other combinations I may have thought off...

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
/*message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}*/

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

and request.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package greeter;  // needles to say this was commented out in all my attempts

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}
```

Here's what the Solution Explorer shows:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As I expected answer is as simple as the question – **this was just a lucky guess!** – the import should look like

```
import "protos/request.proto";
```

Apparently protobuf compiler "thinks" it operates in project's root folder. That makes sense.

One more note – if the imported file defined a new package name this name should have prefixed the message name, like this:

request.proto:

```
package common;

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}
```

and using it in greet.proto:

```
package greet;

import "protos/request.proto";

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (common.HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}
```

Note the **common** in common.HelloRequest.

This simple observations lead to a more general question (and probably a more important one).

**How to import protos defined in another project, say CustomTypes.csproj so as to be (re-)used in a number of gRPC protobuf IDLs?**

I have no answer to this – too much Unix... :(

If somebody knows it, please post it here. I'd be glad to vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking the answer here - you can set ProtoRoot for your proto files in the csproj file like:

`<Protobuf Include="Protos\base_service.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos/"/>`